# Elastic Beanstalk: Deploy Django for mac, CANNOT install EB

Tags: python, django, macos, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to set up Elastic Beanstalk for Django in Mac according to Amazon's tutorial:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Python_django.html

it's fine until **Step 3: Configure AWS Elastic Beanstalk:**

when i go to the 3rd substep "***From your directory where you created your local repository, type the following command.***"

```
eb init
```

The error is

```
(djangodev)Lee-Jamess-MacBook-Pro:~ h0925473$ git init
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /Users/h0925473/.git/
(djangodev)Lee-Jamess-MacBook-Pro:~ h0925473$ alias eb="python2.7/Users/h0925473/AWS_EB/eb/macosx/python2.7/eb"
(djangodev)Lee-Jamess-MacBook-Pro:~ h0925473$ eb init
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/h0925473/AWS_EB/eb/macosx/python2.7/eb", line 17, in <module>
    from scli import core
  File "/Users/h0925473/AWS_EB/eb/macosx/python2.7/scli/core.py", line 24, in <module>
    from scli import command, cli_parse, config_file, prompt
  File "/Users/h0925473/AWS_EB/eb/macosx/python2.7/scli/command.py", line 16, in <module>
    from lib.utility import misc
  File "/Users/h0925473/AWS_EB/eb/macosx/python2.7/lib/utility/misc.py", line 22, in <module>
from scli.constants import OSSpecific, ServiceDefault, TerminalConstant
  File "/Users/h0925473/AWS_EB/eb/macosx/python2.7/scli/constants.py", line 374
    ParameterName.RdsEngine,
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can anyone tell me what i did wrong? Why SyntaxError?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason seems I didn't set the mysql correctly.
please reference to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23260128/pip-install-mysql-1-2-3-under-virtualenv-deploy-django-to-amazon-elastic-beans)